# How to downgrade wkhtmltopdf version from 0.12.4 to 0.12.2.4

Tags: 18.04, wkhtmltopdf

I am using Wkhtmltopdf for generating pdf from Html.

The issue is the output on my local machine is different from the output on my remote machine.

I have read this question and got some source from here: wkhtmltopdf - same configuration different output

Now I checked the version of my Local and remote :

Local version: 0.12.2.4

Remote version: 0.12.4

As everything is working correctly on local I just want to degrade the remote version to match with the local version.

I tried finding the release downloads for that version but I am unable to get it.

It would be helpful if someone can help me with degrading this to 0.12.2.4.

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 on Remote PC.

Comment: You can undo my answer (by `sudo rm /etc/apt/preferences.d/pin-wkhp`, `sudo rm /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf`, `sudo apt dist-upgrade`) and follow other - https://stackoverflow.com/q/18758589/937095 .

Comment: Ok Thank you. But that was working too. I just wanted a patched version 0.12.2.4